# Change field _id mongoose to autoincrement

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to change _id in mongoose, but I have problem with scope and I can not resolve.

```
patrimonioSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if(this.isNew){
    var doc = this;

    counter.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'entityId'},{$inc: { seq: 1} },{new: true, upsert: true})
    .then(function(count) {
      console.log("...count: "+JSON.stringify(count));
      doc._id = count.seq; //dont change, variable local

      next();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("counter error-> : "+error);
        throw error;
    });

  }else{
    next()
  }
});
```

Someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: For `findByIdAndUpdate` you need to specify an ID yourself for the lookup part so I don't see how you can let the server generate the ID for you... ?

Comment: when declaring `var doc = this`, I get the document coming from the post, I would like to change the _id of that document before going to mongodb.
The findByIdAndUpdate function returns to the `then ()` that document:
`{" _id ":" entityId "," seq ": 30," __v ": 0}`

But within the `then (count)` function the `doc` variable does not exist.

Comment: `doc` is still valid within the `then` callback. What are you seeing that makes you think it isn't?

Comment: JohnnyHK, inside of the `then(count)` the variable `doc` dont exists. That's the problem. When i do `doc._id = count.seq` the `var doc` dont change, but create new variable.